# What is the default command for quick build in texmaker?

Tags: texmaker

Does anyone know what the default command for quick build in texmaker is?

I changed it before but now I want it back to default and I can't remember what it was.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall can save your time significantly.

Comment: Goto 'Options - Configure TeXmaker - Shortcuts - Menus - Tools' and customize it.

Comment: BTW, the default shortcut of quick build is `F1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a fresh install, the quick build is set to `PdfLaTeX + View PDF` as shown in the screenshot below for `version upto 4.0.4`):

[image]

In the `Commands` tab you can find the exact meaning of this combo. For reference, PdfLaTeX translates into:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

where `%` is replaced by the name of the master document (e.g. main.tex).

With `Version 4.1 dated Oct 29 2013` the `Quick Build` Command has more options. F1 is the always `shortcut` keystroke to execute `Quick Build` in Texmaker which can be changed via `Shortcuts` menu in `Configure Texmaker`.

[image]