# What application for plainTeX to choose?

Tags: texmaker, plain-tex

I need an application like TeXmaker, for plainTeX, which will be convinient to use and will have text editor, command line interface and real-time viewer for pdf dokument all in one. 
Maybe there is an opportunity to install plainTeX in TeXmaker?
Thank you for your answer

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do the posting [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5001) and the Wikipedia page [Comparison of TeX editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors) answer your questions?

Comment: You don't install TeX into TeXmaker. TeXmaker calls TeX and friends. Since not many people uses plainTeX these days you'll have to define your own compilation command and choose it in the quickbuild.

Comment: texstudio-- sublime text --- atom --

Comment: To add to the comments above: you can use _every_ editor for plainTeX, so you can also use TeXmaker if that is your preferred editor. Just set the correct build command (in the User field, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147817/what-is-the-default-command-for-quick-build-in-texmaker).